# mat-slide-toggle display data. Angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I write a code for display data in html. I want to display data in mat-slide-toggle. Everything looks good, my mat-slide-toggle work good, by in html doesn't display checked when value is 1 or not checked where value is 0.
Can you suggest me any idea please?

My html code:

```
   <form [formGroup]="productform" class="col s12" materialize>
                <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active" id="device" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="devicee[i]" (click)="onproduct()">
                </mat-slide-toggle>
                {{device}}
              </form>
```

And my ts code:

```
   this.productform= this.fb.group({
      'active': new FormControl('', Validators.required),

    });
   populateFormProduct() {
        this.productform.setValue({
          active: this.device
        })
        console.log(this.device)
      }



  onChange(value) {

    if (value.isChecked === true) {
      this.device = 1; 
    } else  {
      this.device = 0;
    }

  }
```

I want to set `active: this.device` because I want to choose in html this value.

Thank you for your help. Please write me for any question.

Answer (score 0):

When I use this html code:

```
  <mat-slide-toggle  formControlName="active" (change)="onChange($event)" (click)="onproduct()"></mat-slide-toggle> {{device}}
```

the result is like in photo:

[image]

Device are always checked. In this parts I want  to display checked only when status is 1, and not checked where status is 0.

When I use this html code

```
<button formControlName="active" (click)="onChange($event) ; onproduct()"></button>
```

The result like in photo

[image]